# Global name 'paramiko' not defined when using module in web2py

Tags: python, python-2.7, web2py, web2py-modules

I am running the source version of web2py from an Ubuntu VM and Python 2.7. I'm trying to use the Paramiko library for SSH functionality, but the following code gives this error:

**Code**

`from paramiko import client`

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/localadmin/scanme/gluon/restricted.py", line 227, in restricted
    exec ccode in environment
  File "/home/localadmin/scanme/applications/nmap/controllers/default.py", line 418, in <module>
  File "/home/localadmin/scanme/gluon/globals.py", line 417, in <lambda>
    self._caller = lambda f: f()
  File "/home/localadmin/scanme/applications/nmap/controllers/default.py", line 50, in login
    except paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException:
NameError: global name 'paramiko' is not defined
```

What is confusing me is that importing and using the paramiko library works perfectly fine on my system when I run Python outside of web2py.

I thought that all modules available in my local Python install were supposed to be available in web2py when using the source version. This is how i launched the web server from the command line:

`python2.7 web2py.py`

Does anyone know what may be causing this issue? It's worth noting that I have not found a "paramiko" directory on my system after installing the library like I have with other modules that are working in web2py.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your import statement is:

```
from paramiko import client
```

But in your code, you have:

```
except paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException
```

In order to reference `paramiko`, you must import it:

```
import paramiko
```

Comment: I tried that and now the error happens in this line: `session.connection = ssh(credentials.vars.host_address, credentials.vars.username, credentials.vars.password)` and says "**<type 'exceptions.NameError'> global name 'ssh' is not defined**"

Comment: Never mind, I figured out the issue. I didn't realize that when I copied the script over from my local machine into web2py, I didn't copy the part where I defined the class "**ssh**". Thanks!